# Error: “has been blocked by CORS policy" en Angular al tratar de enviar mis datos del formulario de contacto

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

hola estoy tratando de enviar mis datos del formulario de contacto pero me sale este error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo para enviar mensajes es un backend que se subio al hosting
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la parte de angular:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me podrian ayudar a ver cual es el error o que me hace falta para que funcione porque localmente funciona a la perfeccion pero al subirlo al hosting ya no

Answer (score 0):

usa este:

```
// Cors politics
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
  },
  methods: "GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, POST",
  preflightContinue: false,
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
  exposedHeaders: ["Content-Disposition"]
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con el cors de secapruh.com.mx. Está configurado para que no le hagan solicitudes desde http://localhost:4200.

En el backend de ese sitio tienes que configurar el cors para que permita solicitudes desde http://localhost:4200